# How to get mouseclick event to remove correct list item when click delete button

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble a todo list app.
I have a user submitting input and displaying this in a bar onscreen.

on submit the user gets a bar with:

.done (toggle button)
.their own input as a 'string'
.a delete button with which to delete the entry they choose.

right now when the user clicks anywhere in the bar, it deletes the entry. i want this to only happen when they click the delete button.

how do i change the click event to only affect the delete button?

Thank you.

(p.s.) its written in typescript but processed, so thats why theres such over specification.

```js
"use strict";
const todoListElement = document.getElementById('ordered-todo-list');
const form = document.getElementById('todo-form');
todoListElement === null || todoListElement === void 0 ? void 0 : todoListElement.addEventListener("click", todoListEraser);
function todoListEraser(event) {
    /* const target = event.target as HTMLElement;*/
    var _a;
    (_a = event.target.closest('.list-item')) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.remove();
}
function todoListCreator() {
    // turn the input text into variable:
    const item = document.getElementById('todo-input').value;
    /*-------------------------------------------------template*/
    const templateOfList = document.getElementById('list-item-template').content;
    const copyHTML = document.importNode(templateOfList, true);
    /*Give <p> element the textcontent of item (user input)*/
    copyHTML.querySelector('.task-text').textContent = item;
    /*Add the template content to ordered list*/
    todoListElement === null || todoListElement === void 0 ? void 0 : todoListElement.appendChild(copyHTML);
}
/* prevents page from reloading on submit, and resets user input field to blank after
submit.*/
form === null || form === void 0 ? void 0 : form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // resets input field to blank after user submits task
    const resetInput = document.getElementById('todo-input');
    resetInput.value = '';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>To do list</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="/images/favicon-pineapple.jpg">
</head>
<body>


<h1 class="title">todos</h1>
<form id="todo-form" onsubmit="todoListCreator()">
    <button id="scrolldown-menu-toggle">˅</button>
    <input type="text" id="todo-input" placeholder="Fill in your plan" maxlength="30">
</form>

<template id="list-item-template">
    <li id="list-item">
        <input type="checkbox" class="status-toggle" name="form-checkbox">
        <p class="task-text"></p>
        <button class="delete">X</button>
    </li>
</template>

<ol id="ordered-todo-list">
</ol>


<footer class="info">
    <p>Double click to edit a todo.</p>
    <p>Created by Thomas Brom.</p>
</footer>


<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new function say, named "deleteNote". Write your implementation to delete note in that function.

In  `<button class="delete">X</button>` add onClick = {//call deleteNote method here}.

Something like this:

```
 <button class="delete" onClick = "deleteNote()">X</button>
```

Comment: I tried this, the problem i ran into was that i had no control over which <li> in the ordered list would be deleted.

Comment: use dynamically set id to differentiate li's.